# How could you add clickable text hyperlinks in YouTube comments?

Tags: youtube, links, comments, url

I found someone post the YouTube comments on YouTube like this:

[image]

It's a clickable text hyperlink, how to do?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-o_tKxCXac

Answer (score 1):

I have been putting up quality content that is being shared by some of the top content
on the internet but am still unable to perform better in search.
My URL is `[https://actogames.com/][1]` from the team looking into this.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/156279)

Answer (score 0):

It is automatic, when a piece of text in the comment is similar to an URL.

If you add the text Wdsep.com in a comment, after you post it, a link will automatically be created.

Comment: If you are the video owner,you may post the the outside link,but if not yours,you can't send any outside links on the comments.

Comment: Thank you @SlinaWilliams, I was not aware. Will have it in mind in the future.